# Происхождение слова "бухать"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Есть просторечное слово "бухать" (или жаргонизм — не знаю точно). А какова его этимология?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что имеется в виду БУХ**А**ТЬ 'пить спиртное'. В Словаре русского арго указывается такой возможный вариант происхождения данного слова: ср. уг. «бухарики» -- выпивка, пьяницы; «бухарь» -- пьяный; «бухлянка» -- бутылка; возм. связано с БУЦАТЬ, ср. офен. и уг. «бусать», «буснуть» -- пить вино, водку. Возм. из тюрк. bus -- объедаться, обжираться.

В словаре Фасмера нашла еще одну подсказку. Было (и, возможно, сейчас существует)слово БУХ**А**РКА со значением "рюмка", вероятно, заимств. через укр., блр. пухар "кубок", польск. puchar из д.-в.-н. behhari, pehhari "кубок". Эта версия мне кажется более правдивой.

Есть еще слово Б**У**ХАТЬ. Но вас, видимо, оно не интересует.

Comment: Вот бухарка - это по делу. Смучает только крайняя нераспространённость слова-основы. 

Уголовный же жаргон друг на друге основан, ничего не даёт в плане исходного слова, остальное как-то очень сомнительно: буцать, буснуть совершенно другие морфы.

Answer (score 1):

Как и у всякого жаргонима, этимология затруднена.
Связывают со звукоподражательных "бух", "бУхать", в одном из значений - валить, класть без расчета или меры. При таком предположении бухать - пить безрассудно, без меры, не соблюдая этикета.
Мне кажется несколько сомнительным, во-первых, смещение уларения, и во-вторых, сама возмодность употребления бУхать по отношению к чему-то жидкому (хотя именно такое употребление фиксируется у Даля).

Answer (score 1):

"Бухарик" это гранёный стакан, производившийся на заводе им. Бухарина. После того, как Бухарина из вождя революции сделали "врагом народа" в 30-е годы, наверное возникло такое ругательное слово в отношении пьющих.

Comment: Да, это известная история про название стакана. Но насколько оно могло перекинуться на пользователей этого стакана?

Comment: Поддерживаю версию @Сергей . Слово <<БУХАТЬ>> привилось уже в советское время , не ранее конца 40-х . Поэтому , польское и древне-верхне-немецкое влияние тут имеет мизерную вероятность , даже через украiнскую мову . К тому же , доподлинно употребляется и слово <<БУХАРИК>> в смысле "алкоголик" , "пьяница" , а оно точно соответствует названию стакана завода им. Бухарина . Мне приходилось слышать и <<БУХАЧ>> . От украинского <<ПУХАР>> могло бы получиться <<пухарник>> или <<пухарщик>> , но никак не <<БУХАРИК>>

Answer (score 0):

Бахус (Бухас), он же Дионис - создатеть вина. Кроме вина, Дионис изобрел «пиво»
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дионис](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81)

Comment: Возможно, хотя и спорно. Но допустим. А ответ-то какой?  Бухать - от Бахуса? А вам не кажется, что сам переход Бахус <  Бухас (или наоборот) крайне сомнителен ро фонетическим соображениям?

Answer (score -1):

"Буха" - изготавливаемый в Тунисе алкогольный напиток из ягод инжира. С арабского языка слово "буха" переводится как "пары алкоголя".

Comment: А как оно на русскую почву могло попасть, не просветите?