# Происхождение слова "буханка"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а что за слово "буханка"? От какого корня оно образовано? Невольно напрашивается связь со словом "бухать")))
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Старшее значение слова "буханка" - это хорошо испеченный, пышный хлеб, потом - цельный хлеб круглой формы.

"Домостро́й" (XVI век) советует:  хлеба печИ квасны и бухОны. "Бухоный" хлеб (бухонънъ)-  пухлый и пышный. На Украине (1523 г.) он назывался "бохон или бохунець".

В словаре Даля есть глагол "бухонить" со значением "теплеть" (о погоде) или становиться пышным, мягким, набухшим. В говорах встречается "бухоня" - толстяк.

О.-с. корнень buch, то же,что в "набухать". Предполагают, что славянские слова с этим корнем связаны с немецким fochenz  - вид белого хлеба, которое в конечном счете восходит к латинскому focus  - очаг, огонь, пламя. (В доме каждого жителя Древнего Рима при входе обязательно находился focus - священный семейный очаг, в котором постоянно поддерживался огонь).

А вот у жаргонного слова "бухАть" в значении "пить спиртное" этимология неясная, версий много, например:
 [Происхождение слова "бухать"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/49730799

Answer (score 3):

Если уж тесто замешивается на дрожжах и разбухает, то почему бы и алкогольному продукту, на тех же самых дрожжах разбухшему, не получить похожее на буханку наименование - "бухло"?
Наворачивается мысль... что *бухнуть = пухнуть*.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "бухать" в смысле "пить", "напиться" вообще стало использоваться в конце 90-х 20 века, а до этого ударение было на только на первый слог и других значений не было. Это как словом "трахнуть" - только с подачи В.Цоя, как говорят, появилось иное значение...